Can all commands be overwritten at once?
Suppose I want to add a log at the beginning of each command and at the end of each command. I want to be able to do that for all commands at once. So I tried:
// Define a function to intercept custom commands
const logCustomCommand = (originalFn) => {
    return function () {
        const commandName = originalFn.name;
        cy.log(`Custom Command: ${commandName} - Started`);

        // Execute the original custom command function
        const result = originalFn.apply(this, arguments);

        cy.log(`Custom Command: ${commandName} - Ended`);

        return result;
    };
};

// Intercept all custom commands to add logging
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('*', logCustomCommand);

But I got:

Cannot overwrite command for: *. An existing command does not exist by that name.

Can you advise please?


is not listing all commands, instead you will have to manually call overwrite on every command. Maybe the Cypress.Commands object can list all commands


The obvious approach is to create a list of the command you want to apply:
const commands = ['check', 'uncheck', 'click', 'dblclick', 'rightclick'...]
commands.forEach(command => {
  Cypress.Commands.overwrite(command, logCustomCommand)
})

Or if you struggle with typing command names into the editor:
Object.keys(cy.commandFns).forEach(command => {
  Cypress.Commands.overwrite(command, logCustomCommand)
})


Also works for custom commands
Cypress.Commands.add('aCustomCommand', () => {
  return 'I-appear-in-cy-commands'
})

const commandNames = Object.keys(cy.commandFns)
expect(commandNames).to.include('aCustomCommand')



Thank you Bijan for your time.
Does your solution refer also to custom commands or only built-in?
And where should I locate your code? On the commands file before() hook?

I will accept your answer, with the caveat that it does not deal with custom commands. Thanks again

You have a mistake somewhere, it does work with custom commands.
